# How to check if DOM/HTML element attribute name is valid in Javascript/JSX? (to prevent invalid character exception)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jsx

Setting an attribute on DOM element may throw an exception if the name is invalid. The docummentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute mentions the exception that gets thrown:

> InvalidCharacterError
> The specified attribute name contains one or more characters which are not valid in attribute names.

How can I check (in Javascript, or JSX) if an HTML attribute name is valid or not? I would like to do a simple check on the string before setting the attribute at all, so I can abort before this error occurs.

Comment: What have you tried? You could create an element in memory and `try/catch` the attempt.

Comment: @chazsolo Unfortunately I can't even find the specification of what is a valid attribute name. If I had that, I could write a regex. But I was hoping JS had something built-in for this that I just failed to find via Google so far. Can you post your try/catch suggestion as an answer?

Comment: [Here's the docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) and the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#:~:text=Attribute%20names%20must%20consist%20of,are%20not%20defined%20by%20Unicode.)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");

try{
    //attribute name is invalid so it will throw an error
    element.setAttribute("", "value");
}
catch(error){
    console.log("Invalid Attribute Name");
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myElement"></h1>
```

Comment: `document.createElement("div").setAttribute("not-in-the-spec", "value")` will work just fine, so this isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
const validAttrs = ['class', 'style'] // add the ones you want

function isValidAttr (attrName) {
  return validAttrs.indexOf(attrName) !== -1
}

isValidAttr('class') // true
isValidAttr('div') // false
```

Comment: While I suppose this would work, I wouldn't recommend it. The overhead of maintaining such a [list and validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) would be a nightmare.

Comment: I completely agree with you but this is a solution to what he asked for "I would like to do a simple check on the string before setting the attribute at all, so I can abort before this error occurs."

Answer (score 0):

```
const isValidAttribute => (attr) {
    const unacceptableAttributes = [
        //Anything you dont want added here
    ]
    //make this false to prevent adding javascript events
    const allowEvents = true;

    //testing if it is a valid attribute
    const el = document.createElement("div")
    let answer = false;
    try {
        element.setAttribute(attr)
        answer = true
    } catch (e) {}
    el.remove;

    if (!answer ||
        !allowEvents && attr.startsWith("on") ||
        unacceptableAttributes.indexOf(attr) !== -1) {
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```